# Some apps during Remote Desktop session can't get focus

Tags: remote-desktop

When I log into my XP computer with two monitors using Remote Desktop, some apps can't get focus. When I click on the app, the title bar background indicates it didn't get focus and when I right click on the app icon in task bar, I don't get the menu which has the minimize/maximize/restore options.

Any tips on having the app get focus?

Comment: The issue might be related to using dual monitors. I have't done testing to confirm this as it's not a big issue. I launch another instance of the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like when I have windows that were open in the second monitor.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that there is an off screen / minimized "Action Box" (Click Ok here, Click Cancel, etc). These need to be acted upon before your mouse can click on anything else. It's happened to me before via RDP. Just Alt_Tab till you find the box.

Answer (score 1):

If the window is off-screen and you can't click on it, then the best way to recover from that is to hit `alt+space` (bring up application window), followed by `m` (for move), then any arrow key (this tricks windows into binding your mouse), and the window will be attached to your mouse.

If the window beeps at you when you click on it in the taskbar, you have a modal dialog open from that process, and you should close it first. To do this, `alt-tab` until you find the window that has the icon that looks like a gray rectangle. It's generally either directly before, or directly after the application that launched it.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this before when the application in question is on the secondary monitor. *Generally*, I've been able to use the Alt-Space menu and resize and move the window(s) in question, but not always.

You *might* also try right-clicking on the desktop, going to Properties and temporarily turning off the second monitor.

Not sure if that works over RDP, however.